# Any tool to trace the sequence of Android code flow?

Tags: android, callstack

Is there any tool where we can find the flow of the android code in huge code for particular sequence, to trace the particular sequence. This is so that we could improvise on that particular sequence. If there is any please tell me about.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for a way to run your code backwards to find an error, or do you simply want to step through the execution of a particular piece of code?

Comment: @evilcandybag I suspect it's the latter.

Comment: -1 This question is covered in coding 101 and the SDK doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just use the debug tool in android and create a breakpoint. From that you can move through the code step by step.

Comment: Thanks, that really works, and here is an excellent tutorial on how to use breakpoints in Android Studio. https://www.strv.com/blog/debugging-in-android-studio-as

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Dalvik Debug Monitor (part of Android SDK, in ...\android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat) to see the complete trace.